# event.consume() method doesn't work in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Following is my code. But when I'm inserting numbers still textfield display it. why is that?

```
    supMobileText1.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {
                event.consume();
                System.out.println("Number Type");
            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: Why do you need to consume the event?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I want ti avoid user to input numbers in this textfield (javafx). When ever user is typing numbers in textfield it not display and accept. So that is I want to do. Above code is working in others code. But not in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This will only allows input of letters

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]*");
        UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = c -> {
            if (pattern.matcher(c.getControlNewText()).matches()) {
                return c ;
            } else {
                return null ;
            }
        };
        TextFormatter<String> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(filter);
        textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);

        Scene scene = new Scene(textField);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```